# How to export Python kiwi project to .apk package?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x

I am trying to get `.apk` Export from Python Kiwi Project but I can't find a solution.

I followed all the steps in from the official repo [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/), but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  "it doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use kivy buildozer which available in github :
[kivy/buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer)